# How to preserve System.Threading.Timer when function is call again

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am doing a simple System.Threading.Timer testing because I want to use it in my window services . The Problem I facing is when I call again the function where the Timer is , existing running time will be gone , how do I preserve it ?

Class File : -

```
namespace Worker
{
 public class ProcessingWork
 {
    public void testTimer()
    {
        DataTable WorkCheck = getNewWork(); // Get new work from Database if there is any
        foreach (DataRow dr in WorkCheck.Rows)
        {
            if (dr["IsNew"] == "true")
            {                   
                Timer JobTimer = new Timer(timer =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("id is " + Convert.ToInt32(dr["WorkID"]).ToString());
                        int WorkID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["WorkID"]);

                        if (WorkID != 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " | Running " + WorkID);
                            ((Timer)timer).Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(999));
                        }                       
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Log
                    }
                });
                JobTimer.Change(0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Program Main : -

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread[] WorkerThread = new Thread[1];
        ProcessingWork pw = new ProcessingWork();            
        WorkerThread[0] = new Thread(() =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Running " + i);
                pw.testTimer();
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                i++;
            }
        })
        {
            Name = "Test"
        };
        WorkerThread[0].Start();
}
```

My objective of this code is to allow the each time keep on repeat. When I call again the function my Thread run and call `pw.tesTimer()` it will check on database is it any new work need to be process . if there is it will create another timer for the work .

Problem I facing is when I call again `pw.testTimer();` all running Timer will just stop and gone . I try without re-call `pw.testTimer();` The time will run every 2 second like what I have set .

What I need is the create timer should always continue run , and when there is new work , it just add on another timer .

Comment: You'll need to store the timer in a field or an array field of the class if you need to store multiple timers.

Comment: @MatthewWatson The Timer should be in the thread pool , by right it will keep on fire

Comment: If that were true then you wouldn't be asking this question.  It does not continue firing, as you already know, your *JobTimer* variable isn't enough to keep it from getting garbage-collected.  It is only a local variable of your testTimer() method, that object reference lives only for a few nanoseconds.  You "preserve" it by making it a field of your class so the GC can keep seeing it being used.  Otherwise the reason why System.Timers.Timer exists, it uses a trick to prevent collection as long as it is enabled.  Don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not because of Timer behaviour , The problem is because of whenever `WorkCheck` table got edit , The Timer that created before is not able to reference the value , therefore the timer will abort.

e.g  In the running Timer `Convert.ToInt32(dr["WorkID"]); //Value 1` , because I do Update the table by `DataTable WorkCheck = getNewWork();` When there is no new Data come it the row will be empty, eventually it will rewrite the table, Thus The first timer is referencing value 1 , but now the value 0. Therefore it causes the running timer to be abort.

I fixed this by Deep Cloning the WorkCheck and the timer should reference the cloning table

From

`foreach (DataRow dr in GJobList.Rows)`

To

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in GJobList.DeepClone().Rows)
```

Thanks for helping .